# Where is the source code for get/post/etc functions in Rails controller specs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

[This page](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/controller-specs/controller-spec!) has a controller spec example that looks like this:

```
require "spec_helper"

describe WidgetsController do
  describe "GET index" do
    it "has a 200 status code" do
      get :index
      expect(response.code).to eq("200")
    end
  end
end
```

Where would I find the source code for the `get` function? I don't even know if that's part of RSpec or Rails.

Answer (score 3):

The code can be found here. Turns out it's part of Rails, not RSpec.

`https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb#L474`